# mailing labels for contributors AND their spouses/families

Tags: mailing

i want to create mailing labels for everyone who donated at X event. Alice, Barbara and Carol all contributed. I want to also make sure that their spouses (Xander, Yancy and Zelda) are also included on the labels so they don't feel left out. When I search for contributors and make the PDF labels, only A,B,C show up. How can I make sure that spouses are included? Fingers crossed I don't have to go in and update all 1300 contact files. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the standard functionality.

However it is possible to develop custom tokens which will print the name of the spouse. I don't know if you have any experience with developing customisations for Civicrm